Missing class org.eclipse.jetty.util.MultiException in Jetty 12
I have this Java code working in Jetty version:
implementation 'org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util:11.0.20'

Code:
import org.eclipse.jetty.util.MultiException;

RuntimeException rethrownException = originalException;
MultiException multiException = new MultiException();
multiException.add(exeption);
multiException.add(e);
rethrownException = new Exception(multiException);

But when I update the Jetty version to 12.x.x Java class org.eclipse.jetty.util.MultiException is missing.
Do you know what is the proper way to migrate the code for Jetty 12?

Now that we are using a more modern version of Java, use suppressed exception.
RuntimeException runtimeEx = new RuntimeException(originalException);
runtimeEx.addSuppressed(exception);
runtimeEx.addSuppressed(e);
throw runtimeEx;

But this can lead to circular references, which some libraries (like logging libraries) really do not like.
So there's a org.eclipse.jetty.util.ExceptionUtil.addSuppressedIfNotAssociated(Throwable, Throwable) to help with that.
The above changes to ...
import org.eclipse.jetty.util.ExceptionUtil;

RuntimeException runtimeEx = new RuntimeException(originalException);
ExceptionUtil.addSuppressedIfNotAssociated(runtimeEx, exception);
ExceptionUtil.addSuppressedIfNotAssociated(runtimeEx, e);
throw runtimeEx;

The ExceptionUtil.addSuppressedIfNotAssociated will not add the suppressed if it would cause a circular reference. (no point anyway, as the information is already present in the stacktrace)
